# Animate UIButton Background color from bottom up, Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton

I have a button which I would like to animate the background color as if it is filling from the bottom to the top.

Right now I'm just changing the color with animation

i.e

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    button.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
} completion:NULL];
```

This works just fine but I'd love the animation to fill from the bottom up like it is filling up with liquid.

EDIT: not sure if it makes a difference but the button is round

Comment: Could you "fake it" by having a colored view slide in from the bottom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. Here btn is the outlet to your button and v is the view we will be adding to your button for animation purpose.

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [self btn].frame.size.height,
                                                     [self btn].frame.size.width, [self btn].frame.size.height)];
[v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
v.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
v.exclusiveTouch = NO;
[[self btn] addSubview:v];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.45 animations:^{

    CGRect currentRect = v.frame;
    currentRect.origin.y = 0;
    [v setAlpha:1];
    [v setFrame:currentRect];
    [[self btn] sendSubviewToBack:v];
}];
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, you sir/madam are awesome

Comment: Okay, slight issue, button is not pressable after transition

Comment: After setting background color, try this -  v.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    v.exclusiveTouch = NO;

Answer (score 3):

`Swift` version of [Avi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685124) answer.

```
let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.btn.frame.size.height, 
                                   width: self.btn.frame.size.width,
                                   height: self.btn.frame.size.height))
v.backgroundColor = .purple
v.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
v.isExclusiveTouch = false
self.btn.addSubview(v)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.45) {
    var currentRect = v.frame
    currentRect.origin.y = 0
    v.alpha = 1.0
    v.frame = currentRect
    self.btn.sendSubview(toBack: v)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need just background color filling from bottom to top, you could create additional layer with that color and origin Y = CGRectGetHeight(button.frame). When you need to fill your button just animate origin Y of that layer to 0.