# How do i create a rectangular slab which filled gradually with some time interval

Tags: swift, autolayout, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

How do I make a rectangular slab like this:

[image]

In this slab will fill gradually with time and with different color.

What I have tried is

```
ParentView(with light Color)
 - > ChildView With dark Color (having heightContraint = 0)
```

Parent View and childView have equal three constraint Bottom, leading and trailing

**Problem** When i'm using this given code, my whole View(View Controller's view) get increased with time what i have given.

Code to perform Animation

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 6) {
    self.hConstView1.constant = 200
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Check this link. You can convert code into swift. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685124/animate-uibutton-background-color-from-bottom-up-objective-c

Comment: You should use `UIProgressView` and just update the progress in animation function.